# Perform Nested Aggregation using Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have data with header mention below. Where 1 org has `n` apps, 1 app has `n` users (same username in different app means different user):

```
org, app, users, spend_time
```

Now, I need to find total and average spend_time per user, per app and per org.

What is the best way to do this.

P.S. I currently solve this by making key of (org, app, user) for finding average spend_time per user, key of (org, app) for finding average spend_time per app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggested approach is a good one.

If you want to perform any aggregation (e.g., a sum) per any subset of the data (e.g., per user), you would do the following:

- Assign a key to each element such that elements that should be aggregated share the same value of the key, and elements that shouldn't be aggregated together don't share the same key.
- Invoke a per-key `Combine` transform.

Here's a partial code snippet that demonstrates per-key `Combine` transform:

```
PCollection<KV<String, Double>> salesRecords = ...;
PCollection<KV<String, Double>> totalSalesPerPerson =
    salesRecords.apply(Combine.<String, Double>perKey(
        new Sum.SumDoubleFn()));
```

Comment: Is it possible to make multiple field combination as a key in key aggregation operation? currently I implement DoFn for joining (org, app, users) to make single key then performing aggregation and split the result.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are asking. Perhaps you want to do one `Combine` to compute all three aggregations you are interested in. If so, you'd have to write your own custom `CombineFn`. The accumulator would be something like: `{ org-count, org-sum, Map<app, Long> app-count, Map<app, Long> app-sum, ... }`. This assumes the accumulator fits in memory, and may have different performance characteristics -- better in some cases, worse in others. Please split this into a separate question if you want more details.